# Trouble logging into Sphere 3D Glassware 2.0 containers on Azure

Tags: azure, containers

I've created a few Sphere 3D Glassware 2.0 VM's using the Azure marketplace, set the username password, and have not been able to log into the Sphere 3D admin panel on any of them with my username and password.

I used the default settings for everything, but still no luck logging into Glassware admin with the passwords I have set - it always prompts "Invalid username and/or password." When using a web browser to log-in.

Has anyone had this problem? Is there something for the container or virtual machine that I have not configured properly in Glassware 2.0 or Sphere 3D's G-Cloud?

Comment: As the poster you always have the option/ability to edit your own question which improves the odds of people reading any additional or new insights/details compared to posting comments. If that comment is the **answer** to your question, please post it as an answer...

Answer (score 0):

The uname/password in question is admin/admin.

In the docs, they say "In the Login dialog box, enter the user name and password for the administrator user created in the Azure portal, then click Login.".. but on the next page it says, "At Step 1, enter the default user name (admin), the default password (admin), and click Login to proceed," when it should be the other way around (i.e. enter admin/admin first, then on the next page your creds).